# Why doesn't the absolute positioned div start from the top?

Tags: html, css

Consider the html and css in [this codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwrjxW).

`#box2` in the page has been positioned absolute and has a left offset of `200px`, so moves 200 px to the right. However, the top offset also gets set to `200px` somehow, but if I correctly understand absolute positioning, it should be positioned relative to its parent (body in this case), and so it should have top offset `0`.

Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: You haven't given it a top: value - so it's placing itself where it was if it was relatively positioned/default place. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/272nq49f/).

Comment: If you try and add a fourth box `#box_4 { background: #ff0000; position:absolute; }` You'll see it will sit below your relative box (#3). If top isn't set, it tries to use it's previous non-absolute sibling's context to determine positioning.

Comment: @jbutler483: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @BoltClock: Not sure if I have explained it well enough, but tried anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your css `.box` you set all boxes 1 - 3 as `position: relative`. 
Your css `#box2` sets a absolute positioning on box 2. The css selector for an id (`#box2`) is more specific than a class selector (`.box`) and therefore `positioning: absolute` in `#box2` overrules the `positioning: relative` in `.box`

You do not define a top property/value in your css for the `#box2`. That means it will flow with the other tags except for the left position.

Because a `div` is displayed as `block` it will display right below `#box1`. It will be drawn 200px from the left because of your css `left: 200px;`

Try to change your css for `#box2` into something like this

```
#box_2 { background: #44accf; left: 150px; top: 100px; position: absolute; }
```

and play around with the left and top values, to understand what the absolute positioning is doing.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence, are you trying to say what's in the first comment? It sounds confusing or repetitive or non-contributing to the answer. It just sounds like it

Comment: @bart I don't understand... absolute positioning will remove the element from the flow of the document and will be positioned relative to its parent... but it seems you're saying that it considers `#box1`'s position while positioning `#box2`

Comment: @anirudh, that is correct. Because you did not provide a `top` value, it keeps the top position from the relative flow. If you add the `top` to the css you will see it will reposition. When the first box is done with height 200,  the next tags top position would be at 200.

If you happen to see a slight mis-alignment, it is because some browsers add margins to the document by themselves. To overcome browser added margin (and padding) you can add css `* { margin:0; padding: 0}` which affects all tags setting margin and padding to 0

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given it a `top:` value - so it's placing itself where it was if it was relatively positioned/default place (As BoltClock has said, this is known as the `static position`).

> For the purposes of this section and the next, the term "static
>   position" (of an element) refers, roughly, to the position an element
>   would have had in the normal flow.
>
> More precisely, the static position
>   for 'top' is the distance from the top edge of the containing block to
>   the top margin edge of a hypothetical box that would have been the
>   first box of the element if its specified 'position' value had been
>   'static' and its specified 'float' had been 'none' and its specified
>   'clear' had been 'none'.

~[W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height)

---

Here is a basic example:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#box_1 {
  background: #ee3e64;
}
#box_2 {
  background: #44accf;
  left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
#box_3 {
  background: #b7d84b;
}
```

```html
<div id="box_1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_3" class="box"></div>
```

---

As you can see, this would also be able to do this using the `display:inline-block` property (since you're removing the defaulted 'block' styling that take's up 100% of the width), which you then wouldn't need to worry about the absolute at all:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#box_1 {
  background: #ee3e64;
}
#box_2 {
  background: #44accf;
}
#box_3 {
  background: #b7d84b;
}
```

```html
<div id="box_1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box_3" class="box"></div>
```

If, however, you *needed* it to only have two squares wide, you might want to wrap it in a container div width and set a width:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#box_1 {
  background: #ee3e64;
}
#box_2 {
  background: #44accf;
}
#box_3 {
  background: #b7d84b;
}
.container{
  width:500px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="box_1" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box_2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box_3" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

---

So, you were right to think that the absolutely positioned element is aligning to the next available parent with `position:relative` (which, just so happens to be the body, since you haven't declared one), you have just missed the use of `top` to position it where you want vertically, and so is defaulting to where 'it would be otherwise' - which is the baseline (which is at the bottom by default in divs)

Comment: This is correct. The "default" position, or "where it would be otherwise", is more accurately known as the static position - [section 10 of the CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html) makes a number of references to this static position in the relevant subsections (namely, 10.6.4).